# Dependencies validation based on conditions using Cerberus

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, validation, cerberus

There are two fields "field1" and "field2". The condition is either "field1" or "field2" can take 'ANY' value, but both fields cannot have 'ANY' value. How to add either `dependencies` or `oneof` or `excludes` based on the above condition?

```
from cerberus import Validator
v = Validator()

document = {
    "field1": "ANY",
    "field2": "ANY",
    "field3": "ANY" # This field can be ANY
}

schema = {
    "field1": {"required": True},
    "field2": {"required": True, "dependencies": {"field1": ["ANY"]},}, # I want this condition to be like "field2"shouldn´t be "ANY" if "field1" is  "ANY" and vice-versa.
}

v.validate(document, schema)  
print(v.errors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made below changes in the schema and it works fine.

```
from cerberus import Validator
v = Validator()

document = {
    "field1": "ANY",
    "field2": "ANY",
    "field3": "ANY" # This field can be ANY
}

schema = {
    "field1": {"required": True, "noneof": [{"allowed": ["ANY"], "dependencies": {"field2": ["ANY"]}},]},
    "field2": {"required": True, "noneof": [{"allowed": ["ANY"], "dependencies": {"field1": ["ANY"]}},]}, 
}

v.validate(document, schema)  
print(v.errors)
```